# PHP variable not being passed to AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Im trying to get my PHP script called from AJAX (that is in my main php file). 
Here's an example of what it is supposed to do: http://jsfiddle.net/xfuddzen/

The HTML source code shows only desk_box DIV being created (which is in my main.php). station_info DIV (being created in the display_station.php) is not there. How can I fix this? thanks in advance

**Problem:** DIVs from my display_stationinfo.php are not being created by using the AJAX call.

**main.php with JQuery/AJAX part:**

```
<div id="map_size" align="center">

<?php
                    //didsplay Desk stations in the map
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($desk_coord_result)){   
                        //naming X,Y values
                        $id    = $row['coordinate_id'];
                        $x_pos = $row['x_coord'];
                        $y_pos = $row['y_coord'];
                        //draw a box with a DIV at its X,Y coord     
                        echo "<div class='desk_box' data='".$id."' style='position:absolute;left:".$x_pos."px;top:".$y_pos."px;'>id:".$id."</div>";
                } //end while loop for desk_coord_result
     ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Display station information in a hidden DIV that is toggled
        //And call the php script that queries and returns the results LIVE
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.desk_box').each((function(){(this).click(function()    {
            var id = $(this).attr("data")
                $("#station_info_"+id).toggle();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'station_info.php',
            data: { 'id': id },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
$("#station_info_"+id).css({'left':json.x_pos ,'top': json.y_pos}).append('<p>Hello the id is:'+     json.id +'</br>Section:'+ json.sec_name +'</p>');
            }//end success
            });//end ajax
            });//end click
            });//end ready
</script>
</div> <!-- end map_size -->
```

**display_station.php (script that I want to call):**

```
<?php
include 'db_conn.php';
//query to show workstation/desks information from DB for the DESKS
$station_sql = "SELECT coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord, section_name FROM coordinates";
$station_result = mysqli_query($conn,$station_sql);

//see if query is good
if ($station_result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}


//Display workstations information in a hidden DIV that is toggled
    $html = '';
if($station_result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $station_result->fetch_object()) {
    $id  = $row->coordinate_id;
    $html .= "<div class='station_info_' id='station_info_$id' style='position:absolute;left:{$row->x_coord}px;top:{$row->y_coord}px;'>Hello the id is:$id</br>Section:{$row->section_name}</br></div>";
  }
}
else{
  // no results - may want to do something with $html
          $html = "no result given";
}

$station_result->free(); 
$conn->close();
echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you filter the coordinate in the query? Like this:

```
$station_sql = "SELECT coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord, section_name FROM coordinates WHERE coordinate_id = " . $_GET['coordinate_id'];
```

And in jquery code:

```
url: 'display_stationinfo.php?coordinate_id=' + id,
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your database connection, which should be on a separate secure page.

`connect.php`:

```
<?php
function db(){
  return new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
}
?>
```

Obviously, your host will not be `'host'`.

Now `main.php`:

```
<?php
// only use for PHP on this page for initial page load - target other pages with AJAX
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <title>This is Where Your Title Goes</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='main.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='main.css' />
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='map_container'>
    <div id='map_size'>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now for `main.js`:

```
//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
var ms = $('#map_size');
$.post('main_init.php', {init:'1'}, function(d){
  for(var i in d){
    var di = d[i], x = di.x, y = di.y;
    var sti = $("<div class='station_info_' id='station_info_"+i+"'></div>").css({
      left:x,
      top:y
    });
    // HTML id, class, and name attributes cannot start with a number
    $("<div class='desk_box' data='"+i+"'>id&#058;"+i+'</div>').css({
      left:x,
      top:y
    }).appendTo(ms).append(sti).click(function(){
      var info = $(this).next();
      $.post('live_info.php', {station_id:info.attr('id').replace(/^station_info_/, '')}, function(r){
        // do stuff with r
        info.html('love:'+r.love+'<br />hate:'+r.hate).toggle();
      }, 'json');
    });
  }
}, 'json');
});
// use CSS to do `.desk_box,.station_info_{position:absolute;}`
//]]>
```

Now for `main_init.php`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['init']) && $_POST['init'] === '1'){
  include_once 'connect.php'; $db = db(); $json = array();
  $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE"); // example only
  if($q->num_rows > 0){
    while($r = $q->fetch_object()){
      $json[strval($r->coordinate_id)] = array('x' => $r->x_coord, 'y' => $r->y_coord);
    }
  }
  else{
    // no results
  }
  $q->free(); $db->close();
  echo json_encode($json);
}
else{
  // could be a hack
}
?>
```

Here's what `live_info.php` might look like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['station_id'])){
  include_once 'connect.php'; $db = db(); $json = array();
  // example only - you will only get one `$row` if query is done specific, so while loop is not needed
  $q = $db->query("SELECT love,hate FROM some_table WHERE id='{$_POST['station_id']}'");
  if($q->num_rows > 0){
    $row = $q->fetch_object();
    // it's okay to overwrite array in this case
    $json = array('love' => $row->love, 'hate' => $row->hate);
  }
  else{
    // no results
  }
  $q->free(); $db->close();
  echo json_encode($json);
}
else{
  // may be a hack
}
?>
```

Comment: why wouldnt I want to concatenate directly in the while loop instead of having that If-Else statement? Also, shouldn't the echo of $html be right before the closing of the connection? thanks

Comment: If you do `$html = 'anything';` in a loop it replaces the old value of `$html`. What if-else statement? No, closing the connection just frees up Server resources it doesn't kill your script.

Comment: I now see that you are trying to do `$(".desk_box").click(function() {` instead of `$('.desk_box').each(function(){$(this).click(function(){`. You need to change everything then. You want a single result, so a different query as well. Give me about 10 minutes.

Comment: I have to go I may get to this later.